# Origin of phrase "no shit"

Tags: offensive-language

So today I was having a conversation with one of my friends and he used the term "*no shit*" to mean that I was stating the obvious. Now I am interested to know the origin of such a phrase. Is it particular to Australia?

**Edit:** I have looked on wikipedia and urban dictionary but both sources only give the meaning/use of the word and not its genealogy.

Comment: Please cite your research with your question so the community does not have to redo whatever research you've already done.  :-)

Comment: There is a semi-humorous "take" on the S-word here:  http://www.anvari.org/fun/Jokes_by_Email/Meet_the_Jack_Schitt_Family.html

Comment: @KristinaLopez I have edited my question.

Comment: It is constructed along identical lines as "no lie?/no lie!", "no kidding?/no kidding!", "no joke?/no joke!"

Comment: Responding to your edit: there isn't a genealogy to speak of: it's just the ordinary use of language. It's just a slightly shorter form of "this is no bullshit?/!".

Answer (score 8):

No, "*no shit*" is also common in the United States. I think this may be interesting to you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit#Shortening_of_bullshit

> The expression *no shit?* (a contraction of *no bullshit?*) is used in response to a statement that is extraordinary or hard to believe. Alternatively the maker of the hard-to-believe statement may add *no shit* to reinforce the sincerity or truthfulness of their statement, particularly in response to someone expressing disbelief at their statement. *No shit* is also used sarcastically in response to a statement of the obvious, as in *no shit, Sherlock*.

Answer (score 4):

The OED has four different meanings for the phrase *no shit*, summarised:

> A. *interjection*:
>
> 1. a. A response expressing incredulity, 'Is that so?'
>
> 1. b. A sarcastic response to a banal statement, 'No shit, Sherelock!'
>
> 2. Affirming one's one statement, 'That's the truth'
>
> B. *adjective*: Genuine, no frills

They say it's originally US slang with a first citation (for A.1.a.) from 1939 in A. C. Bessie's *Men in Battle. A story of Americans in Spain*:

> ‘Sure, they're going to withdraw the volunteers from Spain.’ ‘No shit,..and here I was planning to..grow up with the country.’

For the 'stating the obvious' meaning of the question (A.1.b.), the OED's first quotation is from 1966 in N. Hentoff's *Call Keeper*:

> I..explained what the series was all about... ‘It may show people they're not as different from everybody else as they thought.’ ‘No shit! Imagine that.’